# How to make FFmpeg run according to the date I want

Tags: ffmpeg

How to make FFmpeg run according to the date I want

```
dir/b/s "C:\*.mp4" > list.txt
:encode video
:loop
for /F "delims=;" %%F in (list.txt) DO ffmpeg -re -i "%%F" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 3368k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1920x1080 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key
goto loop
```

Comment: What do you mean with date? Are you looking for cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to run the FFmpeg command based on a specific date condition. Let's say you want to run FFmpeg on `.mp4` files with a certain creation or modification date.

You can make use of PowerShell combined with the batch file to achieve this. Below is an example that will run FFmpeg on `.mp4` files created on a specific date (`YYYY-MM-DD` format).

Here's the code you can use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set your target date here
set TARGET_DATE=2023-10-27

:encode_video
:loop

REM Use PowerShell to get a list of .mp4 files created on the TARGET_DATE
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('powershell -command "Get-ChildItem 'C:\' -Recurse -Include *.mp4 | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq '%TARGET_DATE%' } | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }"') do (
    echo Processing: %%F
    ffmpeg -re -i "%%F" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 3368k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1920x1080 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key
)

goto loop
```

Update the `TARGET_DATE` variable in the batch file to the date you want.
Run the batch script. It will execute the FFmpeg command only for `.mp4` files that were created on the specified date.